# SPOJ PRIME1 Prime Generator: Wrong Answer?

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

Doing [this question](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) on SPOJ, trying to implement a sieve and a segmented sieve to get the desired primes. My code is as follows:

```
//Prime Generator

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //traditional sieve
    int squareRoot = sqrt(1000000000);
    //printf("%d\n\n", squareRoot);
    bool primeList[squareRoot] = {false}; //all primes are marked as true, composite is false

    //make entire array true
    for (int i = 1; i < squareRoot; i++){
        primeList[i] = true;
    }
    //traditional sieve to find primes first
    for (int i = 2; i <= squareRoot; i++){
        for (int j = i*i; j <= squareRoot; j+=i){
            //composites are marked as false
            primeList[j - 1] = false;
        }
    }

    //segmented sieve + output
    int a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a > 0){
        int m, n;
        scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);

        //if lower than this range, then we can just output the primes we already computed
        if (n <= squareRoot){
            for (int i = m; i <= n; i++){
                if (primeList[i - 1] == true){
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }

        //it is beyond this range, so we need to segment sieve
        else {
            int upperLimit = sqrt(n); //highest we need to divide by
            int diff = n - m;
            bool myPrimes[diff + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i <= diff; i++){
                myPrimes[i] = true;
            }

            for (int i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++){
                if (primeList[i - 1] == true){
                    int lowest = m/i * i;

                    while (lowest < m){
                        lowest += i;
                    }
                    while (lowest <= n){
                        myPrimes[lowest - m] = false;
                        lowest += i;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = m; i <= n; i++){
                if (myPrimes[i - m] == true){
                    printf("%d\n", i);
                }
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        a--;
    }
}
```

The basic logic I'm trying to do is:

1. First do a sieve of Eratosthenes to generate all the primes up to the sqrt of 10^9, since 10^9 is the upper limit of n.
2. If n is below sqrt(10^9), then I do not calculate anything new, just output the appropriate primes from (1).
3. If n is above sqrt(10^9), then I first calculate sqrt(n), which is the largest number we'd need, as any number bigger would not be divisible in the range [m, n].
4. Then I'd do the actual sieve, starting from 2, and trying to mark as false all numbers that are a multiple of a prime. I do 'lowest = m/i * i' to get the number that is the closest to m, where lowest <= m. If it is lower than m, then I add until it is just above m. I.E. if m==125 and n == 200, then 125/2 = 62, 62*2 = 124. 124+2 == 126, which would be the first number that is a multiple of 2 in the series [125,200].
5. Then we output any numbers that have no been marked false.

My issue is it seems my algorithm is correct (to me). I'm more than certain my first sieve works, but it seems that it might falter at generating primes larger than sqrt(10^9). However, from my testing it seems it does generate all the primes (and only primes). Is my algorithm to generate primes too uncertain? Is it a one-off issue with rounding?

My guess is that the error comes from

```
              for (int i = 2; i <= upperLimit; i++){
                    if (primeList[i - 1] == true){
                        int lowest = m/i * i;

                        while (lowest < m){
                            lowest += i;
                        }
                        while (lowest <= n){
                            myPrimes[lowest - m] = false;
                            lowest += i;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But I can't tell where. Any tips or pointers would be welcome!

Comment: which is the lowest prime that your algorithm finds? Maybe there is some issue with that particular value?

Comment: Well I start at 2, and set 1 immediately to false. So the lowest prime it would return would be 2.

Comment: I miss the part where you set it to false. It seems to me last time `1` is affected is the cycle from 1 to `squareRoot`

Comment: Well how I've set it up, index of 0 equals the number 1, so the loop from 1 to squareRoot sets index 1, which is number 2, to true.

Comment: I initialized the array with the 0th element set to false here: `bool primeList[squareRoot] = {false};`

Comment: Ahh I see.That was a bit misleading. Then the only place I can think of to be wrong is the one you point out. I suggest you go up to `upperLimit+1` or  `+2` just to be on the safe side. In fact you don't need any square root there. Simply write `for(int i = 2; i * i <= n; ++i)` - this will both be faster and more correct.

Comment: You have read inputs and printed your outputs with *scanf* and *printf* but have included *iostream*. Please include **cstdio** or print using **cout**.

Comment: I have included <cstdio>. I tried with upperlimit + 1 or + 2, but both still got wrong answer :(

Comment: you *can* debug SPOJ, *sort-of*, by inserting `exit(N)` calls and receiving the error code from it. I think it shows the code to you when your program fails. -- BTW, for SPOJ PRIME1, the simple trial division by primes will get you through (i.e. just test divide by the primes from your (1) - or calculate them by trial division too).  for their newer version, you do need the segmented sieve.

Comment: Ok. I will rewrite my solution then. By simple trial division do you mean to just divide each number by all primes up until the square root of that number? Also, where should I insert `exit(N)`? Just all over my program?

Comment: I've made it work. I substituted the else part to do what you said, and it worked. Thanks! And yes all my testing happens in ideone.com

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake , its in the second case where you are defining myPrimes[diff] = {true} . But think of the where the time when input is like 
m = 1 and n > sqrt(1000000000) then it would give 1 as a prime number.

Hope that would make accept you answer.

Comment: :( still wrong answer. I wish SPOJ showed you which test cases you failed